# Convert RTF to XML

Tags: java, xml, text, rtf

There has already been a lot of questions asked about this and I have read almost all of them. I understand that there is no one library that will do everything we want when RTF is involved.

However, I am looking for a fresh perspective on converting the RTF document in the following format to XML .

This is the format

```
      01.   AAAAAA
               01.1 BBBBB
               01.2 CCCCC
               01.3 DDDDD
     02.    ZZZZZZ
               2.1  YYYYYY
               2.2  XXXXXX
                      2.2.1  SUBSUB
               2.3  QQQQQ
               2.4  MMMM


     03.    GGGGG
                3.1 LLLLLLLL
                3.2 NNNNN
```

Basically, the document is not properly structured. It has extra spaces in some places, uneven number of sub lists etc.,

Is there any way to convert it into a structred format like an XML that maintains the hierarchy ?

I have looked into Apache Tikka. The library extracts text from the RTF document, but since the doucment is not delimeted properly, I am not sure how hierarchy can be maintained.

Are there any other open source libraries ?

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can extract text from the document, maybe you could then use regular expressions to parse its contents and create the necessary structure? You could iterate a search for a pattern like `/^\s*([0-9.])+\s*(\w+)/`, then count the dots in first matched group, and add new element:

- if the number of dots is equal to the number of dots in previously processed element - as its sibling;
- if greater - as its child,
- if lesser  - as a sibling of its parent.